# Creating complex mysql view using data from Multiple tables

Tags: mysql, view, rdbms

I am very new to mysql Database, and I have to create 2 complex views using the below tables
[image: Below is the data model]

[[image: I have to create 2 views as in the link][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDOo8.png)

Below is what I have tried so far but still unable to get the required view.
I created a new table to keep the quarter info. Also, I created to trigger that updates the

> year_quarter_period when a new insert happens in the timesheet table

```
CREATE TABLE `year_quarter_period` (
  `quarter` SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_date` timestamp,
  `to_date` timestamp,
  `timesheet_id` int
);

ALTER TABLE `timesheet` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`email_id`) REFERENCES `resource` (`email`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `timesheet` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`project_name`) REFERENCES `project` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `revenue` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`project_name`) REFERENCES `project` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `resource_cost` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`email_id`) REFERENCES `resource` (`email`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `year_quarter_period` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`timesheet_id`) REFERENCES `timesheet` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

This is what I have tried as far to create the first view

```
SELECT project.name as Project, 
       year_quarter_period.quarter as Quarter,
       resource.role as Role ,
       timesheet.hours as Efforts
  FROM project as project,
       year_quarter_period as year_quarter_period,
       resource as resource, 
       timesheet as timesheet
 WHERE resource.role = (SELECT role from resource) 
  AND year_quarter_period.quarter = (SELECT quarter from year_quarter_period)
```

But I get the below result which is obviously incorrect

[image]

I am stuck at this since past 1 day. Can someone assist me on this

Comment: With respect, you should hit the books and learn about how to `JOIN` tables together in queries. The theoretical topic is called *entity-relationship data modeling.* I fear your question as written doesn't contain enough clarity for anyone other than you to understand your problem.

Comment: When you say `WHERE resource.role = (SELECT role from resource)`, the `SELECT` statement must return a single row. It is possibly returning multiple rows. If you are expecting multiple values to be returned from your `SELECT` statement, then change this to: `WHERE resource.role in (SELECT role from resource)`. Or it could be the second part: `AND year_quarter_period.quarter = (SELECT quarter from year_quarter_period)`. One of these two `SELECT` statements is probably returning multiple rows.

Comment: No one *has* to create views. That isn't a thing. If you want help with a query, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query